# iPhone Augmented reality with iOS4 obj c + and Monotouch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xamarin.ios, augmented-reality

With the new additions to the OS and the hardware,  iPhone apps can now do some serious augmented reality coolness.

What are the instant benefots to the obj c crowd? Are there any frameworks to aid in the creation of AR apps for Obj C devs and if so, can they be easily ported to MT with the btouch project?

w://

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I currently develop some proof of concept about AR on iphone.
I know some framework to do this:
OpenCV: nice to do Face recognition, and features recognition in general
NyARToolKit: I work currently on this
ARToolKit for iPhone (from ARToolWork Cie): Professional framework, I'll hope participate to the Beta test soon.

I don't know monotouch, is it work on iPhone?

Comment: Hey 

ARToolWork  is eeeexpensive! Monotouch is a framework to allow developers to code using .NET on the iPhone - check it out, soooo much better than obj c :)